# Read csv column names in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to object oriented programming. Firstly, I am trying to read following data structure from a csv file and parse through the first line (header) and push back the strings into a vector. Secondly, I would like to read the customer information on the first row (USA) and extract the name and  integer value(14400000). So far, my existing code does read the columns. However, there are extra spaces within some of the strings and trim them.

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|,ABB LLC,Phil manu ,Products North America Inc.,Mapn, |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| USA-14400000,,,,                                     |
| Quantity,14155572,14435598,14298563,14311206         |
| Index,US-GC,EU-HT,AS-IR,US-PT                        |
| Period(WEEKS),3,3,3,3                                |
| cost,6278,5341,7394,7069                             |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void ReadTest()
{
  string filename = doe->ScenarioDir( ) + "/test.csv"; // Read data
  ifstream fin( filename );
  if ( fin == NULL )
  {
    cout << "Missing test.csv file." << endl; 
    exit(1);
  }

  cout << "\nReading file " << filename << endl;

  vector<string> suppliersList;
  string str, supplierName;

  getline( fin, str );
  stringstream linestr( str );
  getline( linestr, supplierName,',' );

  while (  linestr.good() )
  {
    getline( linestr, supplierName, ',' );
    suppliersList.push_back(supplierName);
  }
    std::cout << suppliersList[0] << ' ';
}
```

and the output is : ABB LLC

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: neither me... could you please edit your question and show what the first line of test.csv looks like

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as designed.  The following line obviously only prints the first element:

```
std::cout << suppliersList[0] << ' ';
```

If you'd change it as follows:

```
for (auto &x: suppliersList)
     std::cout << x << ' ';
```

You'd obtain the full list:

```
ABB LLC Phil manu  Products North America Inc. Mapn
```

**By the way:**

- you should really replace `if(fin==NULL)` with `if(!fin)`
- and you should loop on a read operation:  `while(getline( linestr, supplierName, ',' ))` instead of `while(linestr.good())` followed by a read that you'd try to process even if it'd fail.

**Edit: how to get rid of spaces**

If you want to get rid of the spaces, use [`copy_if()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) with [`back_inserter()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/)  to do as follows:

```
...
string str, field;
...
getline( linestr, field,',' );

while ( getline( linestr, field, ',' ) )
{
    string supplierName;
    copy_if(field.begin(), field.end(), back_inserter<string>(supplierName),[](char a){return !isspace(a);});
    suppliersList.push_back(supplierName);
}
...
```

This will give you:

```
ABBLLC Philmanu ProductsNorthAmericaInc. Mapn
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your response. Sorry, I guess my question was not clear enough. My aim is to remove the extra spaces. For instance ProductsNorthAmericaInc. instead of Products North America Inc.. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you very much Christophe!